# Secondary Sorting in ExtJS4.1 TreeGrid

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

How do I implement secondary sorting in my extjs treestore. I want a case where all columns after sorting should also sort by gamer.

So imagine I had columns: Gamer, High Score, Hours Spent. If I sort by Hours Spent it will sort that and then order the results by gamer. So if we had 10 people with Hours spent = 20, they will all be shown in alphabetical order of gamer name.

I've tried adding an additional sorter in the doSort method, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

I tried:

```
this.sorters.add(new Et.util.Sorter({
  property:'gamer',
  direction: 'ASC'
}));
```

This property is on the store.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

u can define an array of sorters to `Ext.util.Sorter()` like so:

`this.sorters.add(new Ext.util.Sorter([
    {property: 'gamer', direction: 'ASC'}, {property:'highScore', direction: 'DESC'}
]))`

Comment: sorters for the active sort column are already defined, and i try to put the snippet in my example above in the doSort method. This gives me an array of sorters with 2 elements. I then call the tree.sort method. It doesn't seem to have any effect.